# How can I query a compound index (multi: true) in Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I cannot get this to work. Should this work or am I doing something wrong?

I create an table with an index like this:

```
r.db("test").tableCreate("article", {primaryKey: 'id'})
r.db("test").table("article").indexCreate("root_presentation",[r.row("root_category_id"),r.row("presentation_category_ids")],{multi: true})
```

Populate with some test data:

```
r.db("test").table("article").insert(
  [
    {id: "1", root_category_id: "100", presentation_category_ids: ["1","2"]},
    {id: "2", root_category_id: "100", presentation_category_ids: ["2","3"]},
    {id: "3", root_category_id: "200", presentation_category_ids: ["3","4"]},
    {id: "4", root_category_id: "200", presentation_category_ids: ["4","5"]},
  ]
)
```

Query like this:

```
r.db("test").table("article").getAll(["100", "3"], {index: "root_presentation"})
```

I would expect one document returned, but I get none.

Using RethinkDB 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

A multi-index on a pair of fields will index both fields separately. To query this index with `getAll`, you use a single value that matches one field or the other.

For other types of queries, you need to use an index function that returns an array of all possible values the index will be queried with.

For example, with the multi-index you've created

```
[r.row("root_category_id"),
 r.row("presentation_category_ids")]
```

Your first sample document

```
{id: "1",
 root_category_id: "100",
 presentation_category_ids: ["1","2"]}
```

Can be queried using either the `root_category_id` or the `presentation_category_ids`

```
r.table("article")
 .getAll("100", {index: "root_presentation"})

r.table("article")
 .getAll(["1", "2"], {index: "root_presentation"})
```

Your sample query, `["100", "3"]`, seems to be formed of the `root_category_id` and only one of the `presentation_category_ids`.

The corresponding index function would need to return an array of those pairs. It might look like this

```
r.table("article")
 .indexCreate(
   "root_presentation",
   row =>
     row("presentation_category_ids")
      .map(cid => [row("root_category_id"), cid]),
   {multi: true})
```